# Is there any way to add faded color to navigation bar and UIview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

I have a UIview that contains a label and an image .. I tried adding faded color to the view ..it worked but the color was on top of the other objects which made both image and label invisible...

I need the colors on both UIview and naviagtor[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC9Nl.png) look like this

Comment: welcome to SO, it would be good if you shared your code, what have you tried?

Comment: please share your code i definitely help to you

Answer (score 0):

You can set gradient like this,

```
func setTealGradientBackground() {
    let colorTeal =  UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 128.0/255.0, blue: 128.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    let colorWhite = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    let gradLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradLayer.colors = [colorTeal, colorWhite]
    gradLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradLayer, at:0)
}
```

Comment: For UIView, you can call this function in viewWillAppear

Comment: This way you can add fadded color.

Comment: For nav bar, 
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(self.image(fromLayer: gradLayer), for: .default)